# Isolate certain text in a string

Tags: python, string

I have this massive string in python

```
b'{\n "timestamp" : HIDDEN,\n "profileId" : "REDACTED",\n "profileName" : "REMOVED",\n "textures" : {\n "SKIN" : {\n "url" : "http://example.com/example/123example123",\n "metadata" : {\n "model" : "slim"\n }\n }\n }\n}'
```

and I was wondering if it was possible to isolate the `http://example.com/example/123example123` even if the `/123example123` part changed every time I ran the script.

Comment: You have probably JSON string. use `json.loads` to parse the string.

Comment: do you want to extract the link from there without the "123example123"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, mlghacker-xx! Please elaborate what you have tried so far, the approaches you took, the difficulties you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```py
import re

# URL regex
regexp = r'((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*'

string = "http://example.com/example/123example123"
url = re.search(regexp, string).group()
```

url variable should contain your url even if it changes.